# Power BI Report Server Language Issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have published a report to power bi report server. I can view it easily in my browser but when I changed browser language to Turkish It does not show report. There is no errror on the page. Just it saying loading data and then it shows nothing (BLANK PAGE). There is no error or warning to share with you guys.

If I switch back language to english it shows the report without any error.

What am I missing here? Should I warn my users about setting browser language to english? It doesn't sound effective. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We had same issue couple weeks ago. Change language of IE into Turkish on application server. (country region settings etc.). After that, create new report (.pbix) from zero and publish it into PBIRS.

Comment: Not working to me. Please could you give a screenshot.
I want to change ribon language PBI Report Server.
https://ibb.co/Z6XrnD5

Comment: @MetinSEVİNDİK, we can view some part of screen (filterpane side, some popups .etc) in Turkish Lang after changing browser lang.
About menu-items;
PBIRS supports limited langs. **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions**
And unfortunately Turkish is not among them.

i.e. Dutch is in this list. You can test with it;
* Change browser display language into Ducth
* Restart browser
* Open PBIRS and you will see menu items in Dutch lang.
If you set language that is not in supported langs list, Menu items will display in english mode

Comment: I understood now. I hope, it will be add Tuskish Lang to supported list. Thank you